# Trouble stubbing call to Google geocoding API in Cypress UI test

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress to test a simple react app. The app allows users to search for nearby breweries and displays them on a map. All API calls in the app use `window.fetch`

In the UI test I want to mock a call to Google's Geocoding API but I'm having trouble finding code samples describing how to do this

The [Cypress example recipes](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/stubbing-spying__window-fetch/cypress/integration/stub-fetch-spec.js) show simple examples like `cy.stub(win, 'fetch').withArgs('/favorite-fruits')`, though I'm trying to mock a call to a real RESTful API

Does anyone have an example showing how to stub a RESTful API call in a Cypress UI test?

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#With-Stubbing `cy.route('https://maps.googleapis.com/*', [
  { id: 1, name: 'john' }
])` Now any calls to that url will be stubbed with the fake response.

Comment: I don't believe cy.route support window.fetch. Experimental feature cy.route2 was added which supposedly supports window.fetch, having trouble getting it working.